# Simple property of arrow notation

Tags: ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

> Assume that $\kappa \to (\lambda)^r_s$ holds.
>
> Prove that if $r'\le r$, $\kappa \to (\lambda)^{r'}_s$

I proved similar cases like when $s'\le s$ etc. but I have no idea about this case.

Actually I can't understand why that statment has to be true.

Any help or suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Quick idea : take a $s$-coloring of $[\kappa]^{r'}$ (or also noted $\binom{[\kappa]}{r'}$). Deduce a $s$-coloring of $[\kappa]^{r}$ by extending the $r'$-subsets. Then by hypothesis you have a monochromatic subset of  $[\kappa]^{r}$ of order $\lambda$, and you can re-deduce a monochromatic subset of  $[\kappa]^{r'}$ of order $\lambda$.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues  I've tried that but how can I "extend" r'-subset into r-subset so that they perseve the color?

Comment: The statement is not true in general, despite appearing as an exercise in a prominent textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Given a coloring of the $r'$-sets, define a coloring of the $r$-sets as follows. If $x_1\lt x_2\lt\cdots\lt x_r$, give $\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ the same color as $\{x_{r-r'+1},\dots,x_r\}$; i.e., a set of size $r$ gets the same color as the set of its $r'$ biggest elements.

Suppose $H$ is a monochromatic set for the new coloring. If we drop the first $r-r'$ elements from $H$, we get a monochromatic set $H'$ for the original coloring, and $H'$ is as big as $H$ assuming $\lambda\ge\omega$.